# Area of $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\ 1\leq x y\leq 2, x \leq y \leq 2x\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

Trying to evaluate the area spanned by the set  $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\ 1\leq x y\leq 2, x \leq y \leq 2x\}$, I use the following reasoning:

\begin{equation}
    1\leq x y \leq 2\ \Longrightarrow\ \frac{1}{y}\leq x\leq \frac{2}{y}
\end{equation}

But $x\leq y\leq 2x$, so
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{y}\leq y \leq \frac{4}{y}\ \Longrightarrow\ 1 \leq y^2 \leq 4 
    \Longrightarrow y \in [-2,-1] \cup [1,2]
\end{equation}

To calculate the total area, we integrate the area element $dx\,dy$ over these boundaries. Now, given that the area spanned by a set of points $(x,y)$ satisfying $\frac{1}{y}\leq x\leq \frac{2}{y}$ is the same for either $y\in [-2,-1]$ or $y \in [1,2]$, I conclude that the total area is twice the area spanned by $\{(x,y):\ \frac{1}{y}\leq x\leq \frac{2}{y}, y\in [1,2] \}$.

Hence, the total area is
\begin{equation}
    2\int_1^2\int_{1/y}^{2/y}dx\,dy = 2 \log{2}
\end{equation}

However I am said the correct value of the area is $\frac{1}{2}\log{2}$. I wonder therefore **what is wrong with my reasoning and how do we get the correct answer**.

Comment: Unfortunately, this manipulation of the original inequalities does not work.

Comment: Plus, if you look at [the region](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/nrrfjcru), you will see that you cannot compute this area with just one double integral.

Comment: @Carlo, I would be very thankful if you told me why my manipulation of these inequalities is not correct.

Comment: Essentially, in manipulating the inequalities, you have made the region much larger than it actually is. For instance, the point $(7/5, 6/5)$ satisfies $\frac 1 y \leq x \leq \frac 2 y$ and $1 \leq y \leq 2,$ but it does not satisfy $x \leq y \leq 2x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the simple and nice way Carlo described, you can do it directly...but observe you have an irregular domain, so you must find intersection points and subdivide the domain. We thus can evaluate for $\;x,y\ge0\;$ (as this follows from the domain's definition) and then multiply by two by symmetry:

$$\begin{cases}y=2x=\frac1x\implies x=\frac1{\sqrt2}\\{}\\
y=2x=\frac1{2x}\implies x=\frac12\\{}\\
y=x=\frac1x\implies x=1\\{}\\
y=x=\frac1{2x}\implies x=\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{cases}$$

and thus

$$A=\int_{1/2}^{1/\sqrt2}\int_{1/x}^{2x} dy\,dx+\int_{1/\sqrt2}^1\int_x^{2/x} dy\,dx=\int_{1/2}^{1/\sqrt2}\left(2x-\frac1x\right)dx+\int_{1/\sqrt2}^1\left(\frac2x-x\right)dx=$$

$$=\left.\left(x^2-\log x\right)\right|_{1/2}^{1/\sqrt2}+\left.\left(2\log x-\frac12x^2\right)\right|_{1/\sqrt2}^1=\frac12-\log\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac14+\log\frac12+0-\frac12-2\log\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac14=$$

$$=\log\frac12-3\log\frac1{\sqrt2}=-\log2+3\log\sqrt2=-\log2+\frac32\log2=\color{red}{\frac12\log2}$$

Of course, much easier and faster with variables change...

Comment: Then, since I'm not said that $x,y\geq 0$, shouldn't be $\log{2}$ the correct answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct. It is implicit in the description of this region that $x$ and $y$ are both non-negative. For instance, if $y$ were negative, then the inequality $x \leq y \leq 2x$ would not hold (as this would imply that $x < 0$ so that $2x < x$). Consequently, $y$ is non-negative so that $x$ must be non-negative.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, you're right and I shall fix that in a moment, as the calculations are, as far as I can see, correct.

Comment: That seems likely; I just meant to respond to @Hal.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the assignment of variables $u(x, y) = xy$ and $v(x, y) = y/x.$ Observe that $1 \leq u \leq 2$ and $1 \leq v \leq 2,$ hence the transformation $G(x, y) = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$ maps the [curvilinear rectangle](https://www.geogebra.org/m/yvdsyuwn) $\mathcal R = \{(x, y) \,|\, 1 \leq xy \leq 2 \text{ and } x \leq y \leq 2x \}$ in the $xy$-plane to the translation of the unit square $\mathcal S = \{(u, v) \,|\, 1 \leq u \leq 2 \text{ and } 1 \leq v \leq 2 \}$ in the $uv$-plane.

Observe that the Jacobian of the transformation $G$ is given by $$\operatorname{Jac}(G) = \det \begin{pmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} y & x \\ -\frac y {x^2} & \frac 1 x \end{pmatrix} = \frac y x + \frac y x = \frac{2y} x = 2v.$$ By the Change of Variables Formula, we have that $$\iint_\mathcal R 1 \, dA = \iint_\mathcal S \frac{1}{\operatorname{Jac}(G)} \, dA = \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \frac 1 {2v} \, dv \, du = \frac 1 2 \ln 2. \text{ QED.}$$

Comment: I chose DonAntonio's answer as correct because it dealt directly with the inequalities and still got to the correct answer, although your method certainly deserves my attention and it is actually more practical.